# Bootstrap layout is broken in Firefox only

Tags: css, firefox, layout, twitter-bootstrap

I have to clean up some code and add some features to an existing site.
The layout is broken in Firefox 12.0

See: http://bit.ly/LEqamL

I'm at my wits end. Tried a lot of things but no dice.

The footer and an overlaying image may look broken but when it renders dynamically, it works fine. I just need to get the large 999x666 image to show in the right area.

Any help or direction would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `clear: both` on the `<div id="display">` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my skin :)
Any idea why this is an issue in FF only?

Comment: I can't tell offhand because of the complexity of the page.  It could be something as simple as the vertical extent of the earlier floats depending on exact font rasterization, or it might be due to a bug in Gecko.  Really hard to tell without a smaller testcase.